# Exponential equation in two variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all natural numbers $x,y$ and $z$ such that 
$$(2^x - 1)(2^y - 1) = 2^{2^z} + 1$$

Comment: A part the wrong tag "linear algebra" the problem is interesting. I suggest to rewrite the equation in the form $ 2^x(2^y-2^{y-x}-1)=2^{2^z}$ with $x\leq y$. Then deduce that the quantity in parenthesis must to be 1... etc.

Comment: I haven't done these types of questions before, and therefore do not know how to attempt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with linear algebra.

If you expand on the left, you get the equality
$$
2^{x+y}-2^x-2^y+1=2^{2^z}+1,
$$
or
$$
2^{x+y}=2^{2^z}+2^x+2^y.
$$
The only way a sum of three powers of $2$ can be a power of $2$, is when two are equal and the third one is one more: that is, $2^k+2^m+2^n=2^{r}$ only when, say $k=m$, $n=k+1$, $r=k+2$ (this can be easily seen by looking at the binary representations).

So, assume first that $x\leq y$ (otherwise we can change roles) and that $x<2^z$. Then by the above we have $x=y$, $2^z=x+1$; but $2^z+1$ cannot be a power of $2$. We are left then with the case where $2^z<x$.

That is, $y=2^z$, $x=2^z+1$, $x+y=2^z+2$. Replacing in the last equation we get 
$$
2^z+1+2^z=2^z+2.
$$
It follows that $2^z=1$, so $$z=0,\ \ \ y=1,\ \ \  x=2.$$
The other solution can be obtained by exchanging $x$ and $y$, since their roles are symmetric.