# How to solve exponential equation $2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1} = 9\times2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation states that $$2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1} = 9\times2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2}}$$
The required is to find $$\mid a-b \mid$$
The first thing I did was to devide the equation by 2 to get $$2^{a} + 2^{b} = \frac{9}{2}\times2^{\frac{a+b-3}{2}}$$
I was browsing the website for similar problems and came across one that was solved using binary representation: ([Exponential equation in two variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955162/exponential-equation-in-two-variable)) I tried to put the equation in a form where all the bases are 2 and ask it here as I didn't study binary representation. I used log function to change $\frac{9}{2}$ to a number with base of $2$ which is $\approx2^{2.17}$
The final equation I was left with is $$2^{a} + 2^{b} - 2^{2.17} = 2^{\frac{a+b-3}{2}}$$
I couldn't processed from that point so I wish if someone could tell me if my strategy was right and come out with a solution using the binary representation or something.

Comment: Your first division by $2$ is not correct.  You divided both terms on the right by $2$ but they are multiplied.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Suppose WLOG that $a > b$. Then divide both sides by $2^{b + 1}$:
\begin{align*}
2^{a + 1} + 2^{b + 1} = 9\times 2^{\frac{a + b - 1}{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow 2^{a - b} + 1 = 9\times 2^{\frac{a - b - 3}{2}} = 9\times 2^{-\frac{3}{2}}\times 2^{\frac{a - b}{2}}
\end{align*}

Now you can make the change of variable $u = 2^{\frac{a - b}{2}}$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, write the $ \ 9 \ $ in the equation as
$$ 2^{a+1} \ + \ 2^{b+1} \ \ = \ \ (2^3 \ + \ 1)·2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2}} \ \  = \ \  2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2} \ + \ 3} \ + \ 2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2}} \ \  = \ \  2^{\frac{a+b+5}{2} } \ + \ 2^{\frac{a+b-1}{2}} \ \ . $$

Either the corresponding exponents in the first terms and last terms on each side of the equation "match", or the correspondence is "first term on left with second term on right" and *vice versa*.  You will have a system of two equations in each case.  However, $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \  $ are interchangeable in the equation, so you only need to check one case.